# Silverstripe - adding a blog?

Tags: blogs, silverstripe

Need some help adding a blog for this client in Silver stripe CMS.

The client is http://arborwinsys.co.uk/

and the SilverStripe version is -  2.3.7

Would it work installing this module?

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog

Answer (score 4):

The git master branch that you are looking at contains changes for SilverStripe 3. To make the blog work with your SilveStripe version you'll have to go back to the blog module 0.4 or 0.3 by switching the branches.

Answer (score 3):

Steps to adding the blog module to silverstripe 2.3

1. Download the .zip from https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/tree/0.3
   (later versions of the module require later versions of silverstripe)
2. Extract the contents of the .zip file (it may be within one directory in the .zip file) to a new folder called "blog" in your silverstripe install (it should be at the root level - that is, it should be in the same folder as your "mysite", "cms" and "sapphire" folders
3. Run a /dev/build on your silverstripe install
4. Run a ?flush=all on your silverstripe site

if you have any issues:

- Ensure you downloaded the correct file (later versions of the module will not work unless you update your silverstripe install)
- ensure that you have extracted the files correctly: 
  e.g. if your website is www,mysite,com and you can access your admin from www,mysite,com/admin - you should have your files in www,mysite,com/blog
- ensure you have done a rebuild on your site
- try doing a flush
- if all else fails, post the error you're receiving back on here.

Good luck!